# What's the best way to toggle the MSB?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

So I want to toggle the most significant bit of my number. Here is an example:

```
x = 100101 then answer should be 00101
```

I have a 64 bit machine and hence I am not expecting the answer to be `100000..<51 0's>..100101`
One way I thought of was to count the number of bits in my number and then toggle the MSB, but not sure on how to count.

Comment: Toggle the last bit set? MSB is something different.

Comment: What should the result be if no bit is set?

Comment: You want to toggle the most significant bit or to zero the most significant bit that is one? If you want to zero the most significant bit that is one, how many bits are in the type of `x`? Is it 16, 32 or 64 bits or something else?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Well, in this context how would I define it? MSB would be the first bit of the number from the right. But the thing is I do not want to consider all 64 bits.

Comment: @DanielFischer: If no bit is set, then one bit should be set.

Comment: '*...  the first bit of the number from the right.*', you mixed it up, didn't you? I'd say: ... from the left. @noMAD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cheat is to pawn it off to the compiler: There are instructions in most CPUs for doing work like this.

The following should do what you want.

```
i ^ (1 << (sizeof i * CHAR_BIT - clz(i) - 1))
```

This will translate into the `CLZ` instruction, which counts the leading zeros.

For GCC, see: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

One thing to be careful of is that this results in undefined behavior if `i == 0`.

You should replace `clz()` with the correct intrinsic for your compiler, In GCC this is `__builtin_clz`; in Visual Studio C++ this is `_BitScanForward`.

Comment: `ffs` find the first set one starting from the **least** significant bit. There should be `(sizeof(i)*8 - clz(i))` instead.

Comment: What is `clz()`? Which headers are needed for it?

Comment: @KerrekSB it is GCC intrinsic, there is no need to include any header to access it. You can use `__builtin_clz` alias instead. See also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12534059/545027) for a generic implementation of `clz`.

Comment: @KerrekSB CLZ is a commonly provided concept. It's `__builtin_clz` in gcc, `clz` in OpenCL, `_BitScanForward` in Visual C++, etc.

Answer (score 3):

@jleahy has already [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12533803/545027) a good option in case of using GCC, I would only leave here a generic implementation of `clz` which does not use any compiler intrinsics. However, it is not the optimal choice for CPUs which already have native instructions for counting bits (such as x86).

```
#define __bit_msb_mask(n) (~(~0x0ul >> (n)))   /* n leftmost bits. */

/* Count leading zeroes. */
int clz(unsigned long x) {
    int nr = 0;
    int sh;

    assert(x);

    /* Hope that compiler optimizes out the sizeof check. */
    if (sizeof(x) == 8) {
        /* Suppress "shift count >= width of type" error in case
         * when sizeof(x) is NOT 8, i.e. when it is a dead code anyway. */
        sh = !(x & __bit_msb_mask(sizeof(x)*8/2)) << 5;
        nr += sh; x <<= sh;
    }

    sh = !(x & __bit_msb_mask(1 << 4)) << 4; nr += sh; x <<= sh;
    sh = !(x & __bit_msb_mask(1 << 3)) << 3; nr += sh; x <<= sh;
    sh = !(x & __bit_msb_mask(1 << 2)) << 2; nr += sh; x <<= sh;
    sh = !(x & __bit_msb_mask(1 << 1)) << 1; nr += sh; x <<= sh;
    sh = !(x & __bit_msb_mask(1 << 0)) << 0; nr += sh;

    return nr;
}
```

Using this function one can toggle the most significant set bit (assuming there is such one) as follows:

```
x ^= 1ul << (sizeof(x)*8 - clz(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using a lookup table, assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`:

```
uint32_t toggle_msb(uint32_t n)
{
    static unsigned char const lookup[] =
                         { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i != sizeof n; ++i)
    {
        // omit the last bit for big-endian machines: ---VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
        unsigned char * p
                 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&n) + sizeof n - i - 1;

        if (*p / 16 != 0) { *p = *p % 16 + (lookup[*p / 16] * 16); return n; }
        if (*p % 16 != 0) { *p = 16 * (*p / 16) + lookup[*p % 16]; return n; }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your lookup is running off the end of your static array, giving you undefined results...

Comment: @ChrisDodd: That's because I meant to split it into two nibbles. Fixed!

Comment: The problem with this is that the compiler has no way of optimizing it. If you can't use the intrinsics I much prefer the approach of @EldarAbusalimov.

Comment: @jleahy: Yeah, this solution is probably the most terrible of the answers on offer here.

Answer (score 0):

And to just put it all together in some sample code for GCC:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define clz(x)  __builtin_clz(x)

int main()
{
    int i = 411;    /* 110011011 */

    if( i != 0 )
        i ^= (1 << (sizeof(i)*8 - clz(i)-1));

    /* i is now 10011011 */
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: And the reason for the downvote? Is there no value is showing what others have said in a complete code example?

Comment: The obvious thing I'd change right off would be using `CHAR_BIT` instead of `8`, but I don't think that's nearly serious enough to justify a down-vote.

Comment: I thought maybe a downvote because I took and expanded upon a comment?

Comment: I dunno. I don't see much to really justify a lot of votes in either direction.

Comment: Maybe -- unless whoever did it comments, I doubt anybody can really even guess.